# Female 24-pin 2 row mezzanine connector break out board?

Tags: connector, interconnect

This is a bit of an odd one, but does anyone know if there exists a breakout pcb board with pin headers that adapts to a mezzanine connector? (I hope I've my terminology correct.)

I'm essentially trying to get a board that has a male connector that this (see picture below) cable can plug in to (24 pin, 2 row mezzanine connector, unknown pitch unfortunately) and convert it to a bunch of pin headers.

(That connector is part of a 3ds cartridge slot I'm doing something with, I could unsolder the cartridge slot and put it on a protoboard, but it'd be easier to just have a breakout board with headers.)

[image: 3DS Cartridge Slot connector]

Comment: Sorry, recommendations for specific products or where to purchase them are off-topic on this site.

Comment: Typically, Hirose makes connectors like that. Try to find it in their catalogs. Use a magnifying lens and look for a manufacturer name or mark. If you don't already have a good caliper, I suggest getting one. Measure it's dimensions and pin pitch so you can be sure to find the correct mate. There are literally 10-bazillion different connectors...

Comment: @rdtsc It's not so much that I'm having issues finding a connector, but rather it's finding if a breakout board exists for such types of connectors that's readily available?

Comment: Given the large number of connectors, it is unlikely. But if you can identify the connector manufacturer and series, then google "manufacturer series break out board", it would likely show any hits. Even if one doesn't exist for that specific connector, it might be possible to find one for a bigger connector, and populate it with your smaller connector.

Comment: This is a very relevant question, because it's really hard to identify the mezzanine connector. They usually do not have any label. Is there any catalog anywhere? Personally, I decided to measure the pins step and re-solder a compatible connector with the same pin step.